# Modal doesn't show up using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Whenever I press the button , the modal just won't show up, I tried so many things even creating a custom.js to put this code in

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

But it just doesn't work, Where did i do wrong?

Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Get Started</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/kvq4hwu8/

Comment: You don't have closing tag for your `bootstrap script`!! did you notice that? I  mean you are missing `>` before `</script>`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao must be when I copy paste the code into stackoverflow editor.

Comment: so still you are not getting `modal`? Any console errors in browser?

Comment: Yeah I didn't get any error in the browser. I'm really confused right now, could it be css?

Comment: Even in the code snippet...its not working..but works in the fiddle though

Comment: @SandeepNayak what could be the problem here?

Comment: @JackMoscovi this causing the problem `jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @Shehary I believe you should put it as an answer because it does solve my problem!

Comment: @JackMoscovi answer added with explanation and alternate solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that jQuery `3.0.0-alpha1` version Not Fully Supported by bootstrap `3.3.5`

Reason modal not showing

- either modal trigger by button using default bootstrap behavior OR
- opening the modal with jQuery `$("#myModal").modal("show")`

is because `.modal` property `display:none` is not changing to `display:block`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mo59m6e3/2/)

**Solution-1**

Switch back to last stable version of jQuery `jQuery 2.x`

**Solution-2 using jQuery `3.0.0-alpha1`**

Use bootstrap modal [event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) listener and change `.modal` property from `display:none` to `diaply:block` when modal shown.;

If using button to trigger the modal

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(".modal").css('display', 'block');
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mo59m6e3/)

If using jQuery to open the modal

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myModal").modal("show").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(".modal").css('display', 'block');
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mo59m6e3/1/)

Comment: what about when using data-attributes only?

Comment: data-attributes are default bootstrap modal behavior, modal does trigger but it will not show, it's `.modal` css property will not change from `display:none` to `display:block` so with jQuery 3.x only work around is to use custom code to change the `.modal` css property to show the modal.

Comment: I am using Jquery 1.11.1, and now 2.x+. could you please tell how would I solve same problem using Jquery 1.11.1?